# Autocomplete search taking too long to retrieve data from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, caching

I have an AJAX autocomplete search in user control page, which gets called on `document.ready`. In that we makes an AJAX call to web service which takes the data (which is approx. 90,000) from the database, insert data into cache, returns the data to JavaScript and added to the array.

At first it takes the data from the database and after inserting the data into cache, every time it takes the data from cache. When we type something on textbox it matches the text of textbox with array and displays the list. To get 90,000 items from a stored procedure, it takes 2 sec in local server.

But on live server it takes approx 40 secs to take data from a stored procedure. Also for taking data from cache it takes the same time. How can I reduce the time and increase the performance?

### AJAX call:

```
var locationSearchListData = [];
        var termTemplate = "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>%s</span>";
        var postData = '{cultureId : "DE"}';
        // Ajax call to run webservice's methods.
        $.ajax({
            url: "/asmx/SearchLocations.asmx/GetAutoCompleteSearchLocations",
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (responseData) {
                if (responseData != undefined && responseData != null && responseData.d.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < responseData.d.length; i++) {
                        // Add resopnse data in location search lis, this list is used as a source for autocomplete textbox.
                        locationSearchListData.push({
                            label: responseData.d[i].locationData,
                            latitude: responseData.d[i].latitude,
                            longitude: responseData.d[i].longitude
                        });
                    }
                }
```

### Web-service:

```
    [ScriptMethod]
    [WebMethod(Description = "Provides instant search suggestions")]
    public List<GeoLocationObject> GetAutoCompleteSearchLocations(string cultureId)
    {
        SqlDatabase database = new SqlDatabase(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterDB"].ConnectionString);

        string databaseName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"];
        // Key to identify location search data in cache
        string cacheKey = "auto_complete_result";
        // List to store locations 
        List<GeoLocationObject> lstGeolocationObject = new List<GeoLocationObject>();

        // If location data is present in cache then return data from cache.
        if (Context.Cache[cacheKey] is List<GeoLocationObject>)
        {
            return Context.Cache[cacheKey] as List<GeoLocationObject>;
        }
        else // If data is not present in cache, get data from db and add into cache.
        {
            // Call method GetAutoCompleteSearchLocations of LocationManager to get list of geo location object.
            lstGeolocationObject = LocationManager.GetAutoCompleteSearchLocations(database, cultureId);

            // Checking if lstGeolocationObject is not null
            // If its not null then adding the lstGeolocationObject in the cache
            if (lstGeolocationObject.Count > 0)
            {
                // Add locationdata in cache.
                // Removed sqlcache dependency.
                Context.Cache.Insert(cacheKey,
                                    lstGeolocationObject,
                                    null,
                                    Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                                    Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                                    CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                                    null);
            }

            // Return geolocation data list
            return lstGeolocationObject;
        }

    } // GetAutoCompleteSearchLocations
```

Comment: Instead of writing a pad why not put the code in question? It's better for us if you really need a help....

Comment: Please check the code.

Comment: My advice would be: don't download all 9000 records in advance, that's a huge waste of bandwidth, when probably only a small number are ever used in the lifetime of the page. Instead set the autocomplete to make the request to the server directly, passing in the search term, and then just query the database for matches with that specific item. Then you should get a tiny request and response each time, and a hopefully a much smaller time lag as a result.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The main intention of autocomplete facility is to narrow down the search and bring to front only the nearly matching records to ease the user to select the exact record he wants. Try adding a debounceTime() if possible.
Other options are to fine tune the sql query, implementing the server side paging and checking the page render time in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late reply.
Thanks all for helping me to find out the solution.

We have solved the issue by doing some changes in ajax call. We send the search text as:

```
    // set auto complete textbox
    $("#<%= txtOrtOderPlz.ClientID%>").autocomplete({            
    // Set required minimum length to display autocomplete list.
    minLength: 3,

    // Set source for textbox, this source is used in autocomplete search. 
    source: function (request, response) {      
    // Ajax call to run webservice's methods.
    $.ajax({
       url: "/asmx/SearchLocations.asmx/GetAutoCompleteSearchLocations",
       type: "POST",
       data: '{ searchText :\'' + request.term + '\' }',
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       Success: function (responseData) {                                                     
       response(responseData.d);
   },
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {                        
   }
   });
   },
```

Every time we search anything, it takes the search text and call web services, send the search text to SP, get the data from SP and show in autocomplete search.